# Add menu page is creating submenu with same title name

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using this function to create  menu option in wp dashboard

```
       add_menu_page(
    __('Advertisement Pages'),// the page title
    __('Advertisement'),//menu title
    'edit_themes',//capability 
    'a-advertise',//menu slug/handle this is what you need!!!
    'display_all_ad',//callback function
    '',//icon_url,
    '15'//position
);
```

it is creating menu the name of Advertisement but also creating submenu with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'advertisement_menus' );
function advertisement_menus() {
    add_menu_page( 'Advertisement Pages', 'Advertisement', 'edit_themes', 'advertisement_slug', 'display_all_ad', '', 15 );
}

//and your call back function 

    function display_all_ad(){
        echo "this is call back";
    }
```

Comment: your code is same as my code,nothing is changed.still same problem,this function creating Main title Advertisement and submenu Advertisement

Comment: I tried it but it creating menu title and sub menu aslo

Comment: what is your wordpress version ?

Comment: I am still facing this problem , if you have any idea please let me know .